# About API and Plugins

Tags: plugins, api

It is a general question.

I am not sure whether i could post this question here. As i search in the programmer section and it seems to me that it is meant for in-depth question on programming.

As i am not a programmer ,however,  i would like to find out how is API related to a plugin.. Do they have and difference?

I have  tried to google in the web but not able to find any answer to my own question.

Thanks in advance.

Justin

Answer (score 0):

"An application programming interface (API) is a set of routines, protocols, and tools for building software and applications" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)).
What this means is that you establish a connection to another program / service which provides you certain functionality, like data retrieving in case of the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) or operations and commands like from the [Win32 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Without this interface, there would be no ("easy") way to make use of the program.

"A plug-in [...] is a software component that adds a specific feature to an existing computer program" (again, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29)).
This means that you have already built an application but want to enhance its functionality / appearance. For instance, you have a table on an HTML page but want to make it searchable. You the could use the [jQuery Data Tables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin. In this case you take an existing piece of software and entirely integrate it into your application.

I guess, as a developer you have a very intuitive understanding of these two and thus can distinguish more easily. Nonetheless, I hope that my explanation made it a bit clearer for you.
If not, do you have any specific question?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about the pros and cons of an API versus plugin integration, it is important to highlight that there is no right or wrong basically both have the same nature.

API stands for Application Programming Interface. An API basically defines how a component interacts with a system, facilitating the communication between them.

1. More integration flexibility. The merchant has total control over the integration and can make the checkout page look as desired.

A theme or skin is a preset package containing additional or changed graphical appearance details, achieved by the use of a graphical user interface (GUI) that can be applied to specific software and websites to suit the purpose, topic, or tastes of different users to customize the look and feel of a piece of computer software or an operating system front-end GUI.[from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing))

1. Easy and ready to use integration. Within a few minutes, the payment methods can be available at the checkout.